# Momentum and mode functions in QFT in curved spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, fourier-transform, qft-in-curved-spacetime

While in QFT in curved spacetime, vacuum is not unique, we can still pick one vacuum and have creation/annihilation operator:
$$\phi = \sum_n (f_n a_n^{\dagger} + g_n a_n).$$ In flat spacetime, $f_n$ and $g_n$ has clear relationship with momentum/frequency. In curved spacetime, how would $f_n$ and $g_n$ and $a_n,a_n^{\dagger}$ be related to momentum/frequency?

Comment: Could you say how symmetric you want your spacetime to be? Does it have any translational symmetries at all?